# Scraping Web data from a database platform (VBA - HTML)

Tags: html, excel, vba, web-scraping

I'm not good at developing but I need to complete this task for a small automation project.
The situation is that i have to log in to a database and print out some data to excel, this for checking 
if data is deleted or not.

What do i want from the code?

By clicking on the macro button in Excel:

- Log in into the site [x]
- Search for a given number [x]
- Print back in excel what the status is of the element []
- Repeat from step 2 until there are numbers present in the column A (which loop?) []

https://i.stack.imgur.com/1wbVp.jpg

As you can see in the excel screenshot under the cell A9 is where the numbers list will begin.
Under the cell B9 is where i want my data printed out per each of the numbers on the left.

So I managed to Log in already and search for the first Number.

Here by the whole code:

```
Sub Login()

    Dim ie As New SHDocVw.InternetExplorer
    Dim HTMLDoc As MSHTML.HTMLDocument
    Dim HTMLInput As MSHTML.IHTMLElement

    ie.Visible = True

    ie.Navigate Sheet1.Range("B2").Text

    Do While ie.ReadyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE
    DoEvents
    Loop

    Set HTMLDoc = ie.Document

'Setting Username to a specific value
    Set HTMLInput = HTMLDoc.getElementById("ctl00_WebPartManager1_gwpLogin1_Login1_UserName")

    HTMLInput.Value = Sheet1.Range("B3")

'Setting Password to a specific value
    Set HTMLInput = HTMLDoc.getElementById("ctl00_WebPartManager1_gwpLogin1_Login1_Password")

    HTMLInput.Value = Sheet1.Range("B4")
'Click to login
    Set HTMLInput = HTMLDoc.getElementById("ctl00_WebPartManager1_gwpLogin1_Login1_LoginButton")

    HTMLInput.Click

    MsgBox "Login Succesfull" & vbCrLf & "Press Ok to check LIAB"

    While ie.Busy
        DoEvents
    Wend

    Set HTMLInput = HTMLDoc.getElementById("ctl00_SearchSection_ObjectSearch_txtEMail")
    HTMLInput.Value = Null

    Set HTMLInput = HTMLDoc.getElementById("ctl00_SearchSection_ObjectSearch_txtCustomerID")
    HTMLInput.Value = Sheet1.Range("A10")

    Set HTMLInput = HTMLDoc.getElementById("ctl00_SearchSection_ObjectSearch_SearchButton")
    HTMLInput.Click

    While ie.Busy
        DoEvents
    Wend
'On Error Resume Next
End Sub
```

The second part might be not correct, but that's how i managed to search for that given number.
I have to figure out how to loop until are numbers present in column A starting from A9.

This is how the site look like

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ST63U.jpg

So what i need to print in column B starting from B9 is the innerText of 'Status'.
There is a condition to be met as well and that is if the innertext of status is 'Deleted' but the innerText of 'Name' is not empty then print Error in column B.

So the table in question has  tags with no ID so i don't know how to manipulate them.
Another thing to mention is that if the fields are empty the innerText is shown as :

> &nbsp ;

Thanks in advance for any help and the attention to read all of this.

Greetings,

Alessio

Update changes:

```
'Declared the new variable
    Dim iC as Integer
'........All the login part here........'
    MsgBox "Login Succesfull" & vbCrLf & "Press Ok to check LIAB"

    While ie.Busy
        DoEvents
    Wend
For iC = 10 To 29
'Now able to loop through a specific amount of cells, still not dynamic, still no idea how to pull the data from the td tags

    Set HTMLInput = HTMLDoc.getElementById("ctl00_SearchSection_ObjectSearch_txtCustomerID")
    HTMLInput.Value = Sheet1.Range("A" & iC)

    Set HTMLInput = HTMLDoc.getElementById("ctl00_SearchSection_ObjectSearch_SearchButton")
    HTMLInput.Click

    While ie.Busy
        DoEvents
    Wend
   Next
'On Error Resume Next
End Sub'
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO. I don't understand your issue. Are you getting an error when you run the code? If so, what is it and which line throws the error? If not, are you just looking for help in adding a loop to the code so you can get all relevant cells complete in `Column B`? BTW, for someone who is **not good at developing**, that code is pretty good!

Comment: Hi Zac, sorry to have been unclear. There is no error at the moment, and yes I am looking for help because I'm stuck at that point. Thank you for the feedback, I have spent a lot of time last weeks looking for how such things are done, but every case is different. The problem is that I am missing base knowledge too of syntax and code structure to go on by my own, and I don't have much time left to dive into the basics.

Comment: If it's just a loop you need then after you login (and before you first `Set HTMLInput =...` statement after login) add a for loop: `For iC = 10 To 16`. You can then change `HTMLInput.Value = Sheet1.Range("A10")` to `HTMLInput.Value = Sheet1.Range("A" & iC)`. That will loop through your cells. There are other things to consider: 1. find the last cell in column `A` to make your `FOR` loop dynamic. 2. How you capture results in `Column B`. But IMO, baby steps will help you understand what's going on

Comment: I see, I added this loop and works, as you said i still have to figure out how to make it dynamic and how to record the data. Thank you Zac!

Comment: If I get time, i'll post code to make it so

Comment: It would be great Zac, please contact me if you need anything that could help

Answer (score 0):

As you just needed help with the loop, I'm just posting the code in and around the loop. I haven't tested this code but hopefully it will work

```
Dim iC As Long
Dim iLastRow As Long: iLastRow = Sheet1.Range("A" & Sheet1.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
Dim HTMLInput As MSHTML.IHTMLElement
Dim oSearchButton As MSHTML.IHTMLElement: Set oSearchButton = HTMLDoc.getElementById("ctl00_SearchSection_ObjectSearch_SearchButton")

' Loop through all avaiable customer IDs
For iC = 10 To iLastRow

    ' Set Customer ID
    Set HTMLInput = HTMLDoc.getElementById("ctl00_SearchSection_ObjectSearch_txtCustomerID")
    HTMLInput.Value = Sheet1.Range("A" & iC)

    ' Press Search button
    oSearchButton.Click

    ' Wait for browser to complete task
    While ie.Busy
        DoEvents
    Wend

    ' Capture Status in colmn B
    Set HTMLInput = HTMLDoc.getElementById("ctl00_SearchSection_ObjectSearch_txtCustomerID")    ' Change element ID to point to status element
    Sheet1.Range("B" & iC) = HTMLInput.Value

Next
```

**Tip:** If element ID's don't change, you could just declare your elements (customer ID element and Status element) outside of the `For` loop and just use them in the loop just as i did with `oSearchButton` element

Comment: Hi Zac, thank you for posting this. I have few questions: Can I just add the declarations of `Dim iC As Long
Dim iLastRow As Long: iLastRow = Sheet1.Range("A" & Sheet1.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row` and `Dim oSearchButton As MSHTML.IHTMLElement` at the top under my previous declarations?
Did you declare `oSearchButton` just to avoid repetitions of the HTML ID, and just write down this `oSearchButton.Click` when needed?
About capturing the status in Column B you are suggesting to use the ID method, but as you can see in the 2nd scree the /td tags have no ID! how to solve this?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Yes, you can declare them at the top. Only difference would be that this bit: `Set oSearchButton = HTMLDoc.getElementById("ctl00_SearchSection_ObjectSearch_SearchButton")` will have to be after the page has loaded (so just before the `For` loop). That's exactly why i did declare it outside of the loop: to avoid repetition. More tricky bit is identifying and capturing **Status**. You will have to capture the **table** (I think it has an ID = `grid`) and then capture the status based on the row. there are many examples on how to do that on the web.. if not let me know

Comment: Hi Zac, i searched and found something, but I'm still struggling to find the correct way to extract the status.
`For iC = 10 To iLastRow
Set HTMLInput = HTMLDoc.getElementById("ctl00_SearchSection_ObjectSearch_txtCustomerID")
HTMLInput.Value = Sheet1.Range("A" & iC)
oSearchButton.Click
...Wait for IE to load stuff...
Wend
Set HTMLInput = HTMLDoc.getElementById("ctl00_ListSection_UpdatePanel1")    Set HTMLInput = HTMLDoc.getElementsByClassName("grid")
Set HTMLInput = HTMLDoc.getElementsByClassName("gridRow").Item(3)
Debug.Print HTMLInput.innerText`

Comment: I got Error 13 that the type is not supported

Comment: [Have a look at this](https://www.google.com/search?q=capture+table+from+html+page+vba&rlz=1C1GCEJ_enGB818GB818&oq=capture+table+from+html+page+vba&aqs=chrome..69i57.15959j1j8&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8#kpvalbx=_U080XozGF4rHgAbT9rGIBg17). Not the best coding practice and maybe we can have a better approach but it will give you an idea where you are going wrong